# gRPC asynchronous client streaming to multiple servers c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, grpc

I've been searching the correct way to use grpc client to stream asynchronously to multiple servers, but I cannot find a proper example.

**My goal**: there are multiple grpc servers and I have one client that streams messages to all of them asynchronously.
**The important thing is:** I don't want to wait for each server's response, I want to continue streaming to the next ones and then wait/block for the responses.

**Note:** I know I can use sync grpc with threads but I want to learn the async api.

**Example:**

```
for (auto addr : addresses) { 
    // create stub from addr 
    // auto stub = ...
    auto writer = stub->AsyncMyRequest(context, response, &cq_, someTag);
    /* This notifies me when I can stream the next message (streams only support one message at a time. */
    cq_.Next(&tag, &ok); 
    // check ok, etc.
    
    for (auto msg : msgs){
        writer->Write(msg, someTag);
        cq_.Next(&tag, &ok); // aknowledge
    }
    // Here I want to somehow finish the stream  but not block 
    // for the result. I want to continue to the next addr, stream data, etc.
    writer->WritesDone(); // or writer->Finish() ? 
    counter++;
}

while (counter>0){
    cq_.Next(&tag, &ok);
    // process response
    counter--;
}
```

Can something like that be achieved? My guess is I would need two completition queues, one that notifies me when I can write the next `msg` to the stream and one that I call `Next` to read the next response from each `addr`, but I have no clue how to do this (if it can be done).

Another option would be again to use threads, but I want to know if we can achieve this using only the asynchronous API.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC C++ offers two ways to achieve asynchrony. CQ-based API that you used and Callback API which is new and recommended. So I suggest using it instead for simplicity. If you want to use a client streaming, this [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/15ef046440ef0f4e2e4a9ca4db7cf17b76377162/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_client.cc#L149-L230) would be relevant.